# In different place the distance between items under enumerate or itemize option

Tags: itemize

In different place the distance between items under enumerate or itemize option. Please suggest to set them uniformly as all things in 1.5 line space as my draft.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the space inside an itemize environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{18pt}
  \item test
  \item test
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

It is also possible to use baselinestretch.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize
\begin{itemize}
 \item test
 \item test
\end{itemize}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize

\end{document}
```

If you want to change the space in the whole document, you can simply add these two lines before document environment and change the 18pt to any value you want.

```
\let\OLDitemize\itemize
\renewcommand\itemize{\OLDitemize\addtolength{\itemsep}{18pt}}
```

The best solution is to use the enumitem-package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{itemsep=18pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Now you can change the itemsep-value to any value you want.

To change the item space in bibliography only, you can add this to your preamble.

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{18pt}
```

If it doesn't work, you can also try this:

```
\let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
\oldbibliography{#1}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{18pt}%
}
```

Comment: thank you. But it is not possible to give in a whole document. Can we give it in the preamble part.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Actually, I want 1.5 line space everywhere, whatever it is items or anything. For that what to do? I have already using \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}   OR   \baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip

Comment: If you need 1.5 line space everywhere, you can add \usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing

Comment: there is an option that I like and it is to write \begin{enumerate}[topsep=2pt,itemsep=-.8ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex] ......text..in items.... \end{enumerate}. BUT everywhere I could not give it. Is there any option for the whole document.

Comment: Do you need the line space in the whole document or just in every enumerate/itemize environment?

Comment: I need it in every enumerate/itemize environment.

Comment: You can use my fourth example for that. Just include the enumitem-package and the \setitemize-command in your preamble.

Comment: Yes it is OK.  And one more thing. In case of only changes the distance between items in Bibliography, then what to do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14970/discussion-between-deepesh-patel-and-slx64).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing                %% <--- Better use setspace
\setlist[itemize]{nosep}       %%% <--- no extra separation
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep}     %%% <--- no extra separation
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{itemize}
  \item test
  \item test
    \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \item test
        \item test
    \end{itemize}
  \item test
\end{itemize}
\kant[2]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item test
  \item test
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item test
        \item test
        \item test
    \end{enumerate}
  \item test
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Harish ! Yes I want for same but the given packages not working. And I am using report.

Comment: @DeepeshPatel May be you should update your tex distribution. The above code works for `report` class also. I use miktex latest version and it is up-to-date.